# What is an example of a journal based in China which "warns authors that they are not affiliated with any paper-selling companies"?

Tags: journals, ethics, china

Regarding the following quote:

> ... editors say an increasing number of journals based in China warn authors that they are not affiliated with any paper-selling companies.
>    <sub>Mara Hvistendahl, [China's Publication Bazaar](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/342/6162/1035), Science, 2013.</sub>

Partly out of curiosity and partly because I work in China, I'm interested in finding a concrete example of this.

**Question** : What is an example of a journal based in China which "warns authors that they are not affiliated with any paper-selling companies"?

Ideally, I'd like a web link to a journal based in China showing this warning.  Or perhaps someone received such a warning in an email as part of communications with a journal.

Comment: Have you tried asking around colleagues in China? Usually Chinese journals work chiefly in Chinese, getting submissions of local authors.

Comment: What is a "paper-selling company"? Is that like a paper mill?

Comment: Is a "paper-selling company" a company that churns out academic writing (e.g. like an essay mill), or is it a company that literally sells physical paper?

Comment: @einpoklum While working as a postdoc in China, I have noticed two interesting phenomena: (i) some service-providing companies (e.g. genome sequencing) for academics would offer data-analysis packets that could go anywhere from providing stats to full-blown results description and discussions; (ii) a few colleagues who definitely displayed poor writing and reasoning skills would often come up fair & sound manuscripts out of the blue. I strongly suspect there are companies in China selling seemingly-acceptable manuscript-material.